# PostrgreSQL. Сложный запрос

Tags: postgresql, select

Имеется таблица, из которой я должен выявить с помощью запроса те направления, на которые не было продано ни одного билета. Должно получиться вот так:

```
   departure_city    |    arrival_city     |    max    |    min
---------------------+---------------------+-----------+----------
 Абакан              | Архангельск         |           |
 Абакан              | Грозный             |           |
 Абакан              | Кызыл               |           |
 Абакан              | Москва              | 101000.00 | 33700.00
 Абакан              | Новосибирск         |   5800.00 |  5800.00
```

Я пробовал вот такой запрос:

```
select f.departure_city, f.arrival_city from flights_v f join ticket_flights tf on f.flight_id where max(tf.amount) is null and min(tf.amount) is null group by 1,2;
```

Однако ничего не выходит. Скажите, как правильно здесь нужно всё сделать, пожалуйста.

```
select f.departure_city, f.arrival_city from flights_v f left join ticket_flights tf on f.flight_id where max(tf.amount) is null and min(tf.amount) isnull group by 1,2;
```

Comment: `направления LEFT JOIN билеты` собсно...

Comment: Т.е. нужно просто добавить LEFT к join?

Comment: Если я правильно сделал то, что вы сказали, то это вариано не сработал. Написали, что аргумент конструкции join должен иметь логический тип, а не integer (мне такое писали и в прошлый раз)

Comment: Условие связывания и должно  быть булевым выражением. Если Вы получили такое сообщение - Вы неверно написали условие связывания. Как правило, условие связывания указывает равенство какого-то поля одной таблицы какому-то полю другой таблицы. См. описание [FROM clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM).

Comment: А вы можете несколько подробнее об этом рассказать или написать, как следует выполнить данный запрос?